# My jobs are not being executed by the queue lambda

Tags: laravel-vapor

My understanding is that vapor sets the config for the queue driver to sqs so all jobs are executed on the queue lambda. I am dispatching jobs and can see clearly they are not running on the queue lambda. Did I miss something? env.production does not have an entry for queue_driver as assuming vapor injects it as it does in my other projects.

```
//In a controller
RenamePhoto::dispatch($photo_id,$name);

class RenamePhoto implements ShouldQueue // so we are clear here

//RenamePhoto constructor
Log::info("Adding to the Rename Process ". $photo_id);

//RenamePhoto handle
Log::info("Processing rename of photo ". $this->photo_id. ' to '.$this->name);
```

Both those logs show up on the HTTP logs

Laravel Framework 9.24.0

Laravel Vapor 1.42.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by me missing an update to Laravel in config/queue.php.
`QUEUE_DRIVER became QUEUE_CONNECTION` and a bunch of values needed by aws were added as env values in the sqs section.
Hope this helps someone moving an older project to Vapor.

See https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/9.x/config/queue.php